# Format historic date (< 1970) international

Tags: php

I want to format historical dates: 1635-11-27 => Tuesday 27 November 1635, but i need it in dutch not english.
I'm using dateTime to format but that function does not respond to set_locale. Strftime does respond to setlocale but only takes a unix timestamp which start in 1970, am i right?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [IntlDateFormatter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) [format()](http://php.net/manual/es/intldateformatter.format.php)

```
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(<locale>);
$string = $formatter->format(DateTime object);
```

Comment: Looks like i can't use that class: Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found (php 5.3.5, configured with '--disable-intl')

Comment: That reduce a lot the options available. For your set_locale issue check if you have the proper locale packages installed in your OS. For example for es_ES I have to install 'language-pack-es' in ubuntu (as you can appreciate is not a specific PHP package but is needed for ICU tables)

Answer (score -2):

Why won't you str_replace all "January", "February", ..., "Monday", "Tuesday", ... with their translations?

Comment: Given the fact that intl is not enabled, this isn't such a bad idea actually :)